# Ошибка missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, почему JS ругается на синтаксическую ошибку, вроде все правильно написано.

В чем причина ошибки?

```js
function InfoChange(btnEvent, elementsToChange, classToBlockSelect, classToBlockInput, buttonTextChange) {
  this.btnEvent = document.querySelector(btnEvent);
  this.elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll(elementsToChange);

  this.ready = this.btnEvent && this.elementsToChange;

  if (!this.ready) {
    return;
  };

  this.classToBlockInput = classToBlockInput;
  this.classToBlockSelect = classToBlockSelect;
  var _this = this;

  var buttonAttr = function() {
    _this.btnEvent.setAttribute('data-status', 'unactive');
  };
  buttonAttr();

  this.btnEvent.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var btnAttribute = _this.btnEvent.getAttribute('data-status');

      if (btnAttribute == 'unactive') {
        _this.btnEvent.setAttribute('data-status', 'active');
        _this.btnEvent.textContent = _this.buttonTextChange;
      } else {
        _this.btnEvent.setAttribute('data-status', 'unactive');
        _this.btnEvent.textContent = _this.currentBtnText;
      };

      for (var i = 0; i < _this.elementsToChange.length; i++) {
        if (_this.elementsToChange[i].tagName == 'INPUT') {

          //Change value
          _this.elementsToChange[i].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            var currentItem = event.target;
            var currentValue = event.target.value;
            currentItem.setAttribute('value', currentValue);

          });

          //Change class
          if (_this.elementsToChange[i].classList.contains(classToBlockInput)) {
            _this.elementsToChange[i].classList.remove(classToBlockInput);
            _this.elementsToChange[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
          } else {
            _this.elementsToChange[i].classList.add(classToBlockInput);
            _this.elementsToChange[i].setAttribute('disabled', '');
          };

        }
      }
    }
  }

  var one = new InfoChange('.button--fields-change', '.some', 'none', 'none', 'edit');
```

Comment: Вероятно, ошибка не в этом коде

Comment: @vp_arth в этом, в этом. Не закрыта `)` для `this.btnEvent.addEventListener('click', function() {`

Comment: Так оно и случается, когда в функции, объявленной прямо в вызове какого-то метода, слишком много кода.

Comment: @Regent, и когда форматирование хромает. Оно хорошее, но почему-то хромает :-)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi пожалуйста в следующий раз воспользуйтесь кнопкой "Привести в порядок" в сниппете для автоматического форматирования кода.